# Updating options into the wp database performance

Tags: plugins, database, options

I have a question about the performance of my plugin.

On the settings page of my plugin I have about 20 options the user can change (checkboxes, dropdown and normal text inputs). Currently I just update all options on submitting the form.

Is it better for performance to first check if an option is updated before I really update the option? So that it doesn't write to the database if the option isn't changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`update_option()`](http://queryposts.com/function/update_option/) does this for you already:

```
// If the new and old values are the same, no need to update.
if ( $value === $old_value )
    return false;
```

No need to worry about it. :)

Note that if you have *a lot* of options, which are not autoloaded, this might cause excessive *read* queries. This applies to general operation too, not just updates.

Comment: How do u autoload/update options?

Comment: See [`add_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) documentation for details on autoload, by default it's enabled.